# Display Real-Time Values

Tags: php, real-time

Say I have the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Now, this will display:

```
0123456789
```

However, it will take 9 seconds to load, and will not display real-time.
How would I display it so it would be:

```
0(1 second)2(1 second)3(...)
```

My second question involves overwriting the current data on the page.
For example, say I have the same code as above. However, I want to display each number as itself. So the page would be:

```
0
```

Then after 1 second

```
1
```

And so on.

Comment: Try `ob_flush()` , But won't work on all browsers though.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It's still taking 9 seconds to load (Google Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i."\n";
    $timeFirst  = strtotime(date());
    sleep(1);
    $timeSecond = strtotime(date());
    echo ($timeSecond - $timeFirst)." second(s) \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it with Client side script such as javascript. `DOM` loads only after the complete execution of your server side script.

There is no way you can execute each command and render the output to the web browser, unless you are doing it at CLI or doing it via Client Side.

Comment: How could I execute it server side, and display the data, real time?

Comment: via ajax If you really wanted to execute from the server-side but if it is doable from the client side you should do it via client..

Comment: like if this is the only code you showed in the question It can be done in the javascript no need for server side ajax..

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    flush();
    ob_end_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```